# check DataTable still = null even it has a record in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Table `CLASS(id,name)` in SQL Server 2008 Database

I have a CreateClass function in my aspx page:

```
 public void CreateClass(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string idclass= txtID.Text;
    string name= txtName.Text;

    string sql="select * From CLASS where id="+idclass;
    Datatable class= excute...;
    if(class!=null)
    {
        LabelError.Text="ID class is existed already!";
        return;
    }
    else

    {
        ... write into database...
    }
}
```

Build program, first I input: `txtID.Text= "DDD121"` and `txtName.Text="Class 2"`

It still has 1 record which has `id= DDD121` in Database but the program pass `if` statement and jump inside `else` statement. Why? Of course, in the `else` statement, the new class which id= DDD121 cannot be inserted into Database, but I need the Error Message shows.

I check the sql query in SQL server query window: `select * from CLASS where id='DDD121'` it works fine, 1 record show with id= DDD121.

Try to debug:

```
sql= "select * FROM CLASS WHERE ID=DDD121";
class=null;
```

Help!!!! is  `if(class!=null)`the right way to check if Datatable has no row???

Comment: Oh dear. Not related to your question but asp.net + `txtId.Text` being concatenated onto your SQL = Classic SQL injection. Please read up about using parameters.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to debug, I suspect that you will see that `class` is not null, but it is an empty DataTable.

That should give you also a hint as to what to test instead of `class != null`.

and yes, SQL-injection. But that is outside the scope of this one. I would suggest not to ignore it though.

If `class` is null in debug, while you are sure that a record should exist, i would suggest checking if you actually are connected correctly to your database and if you execute your query correctly.

`execute...` is definitely not working, so maybe in the actual code something goes awry.

Ah, make sure you put your desired value in between ''. Otherwise it won;t work indeed.
Not doing that has little to do with SQL-Injection by the way.

Just a hint, once you get this working, instead of filling in DDD121 in your textbox, fill in ABC';DROP TABLE CLASS; and see what happens ;) *That* is SQLinjection.

Comment: oh, I see class= null when I debug

Comment: it has an alert $exception{"Invalid column name 'DDD121'."} so I think problem is SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(class!=null && class.Rows.Count>0)
    {
        LabelError.Text="ID class is existed already!";
        return;
    }
    else

    {
        ... write into database...
    }
```

This Code check null and empty datatable